# Save Data as UserDefault even after Exiting View Controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to have an array which stores all my data that is received from other VCs. I want it to be so that every time I navigate to the VC which holds this storing array, all the data that I'm passing from my other VCs get stored in this Store array, which I can then present in a UITable View.

And then when I navigate back to my other VCs and collect data to then send back to this storing array, the previous data doesn't disappear.
However, with my attempt, the data disappears every time I exit the VC.

Here's my attempt:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var DataGrab = [String]() //data from other VCs

    func SAVE(){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(DataGrab, forKey: "Save")
        if let ToSave = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Save") as? [String] {
            print(ToSave)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("DataGrab", DataGrab)
        SAVE()
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your `print(ToSave)` and `print("DataGrab", DataGrab)`, are they printing out correct data?

Comment: Yes they print the correct data, except Tosave should contain previous elements. But Tosave is always exactly the same as DataGrab

Comment: The data is replaced, not appended. If you want to append, you need to load all the data, append the array, and write the new, full array.

Comment: FYI - Do not use `UserDefaults value(forKey:)`. Use the proper `UserDefaults array(forKey:)` or other documented method. Never use key-value coding unless you have a clear, specific need to do so.

Comment: And you should not use `UserDefaults` to save data. For a few strings it's fine, but not for general data. Write the array to a file (such as a plist). If it gets really long you should look into a database/Core Data.

Comment: @rmaddy There is an even better solution `stringArray(forKey: )`, since the OP is using `[String]`

Comment: Im storing data of about 100 string values in an array, is that too large for UserDefault data?

Answer (score 1):

First, get your array out. Then, append your new data onto the array you saved in your UserDefaults, Finally, override that array by the same key in UserDefaults

```
if let ToSave = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "Save"){
    DataGrab += ToSave
    UserDefaults.standard.set(DataGrab, forKey: "Save")
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't deal with the initial case of no data in user defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving data Right but when the view is loaded again you are not providing value to it again I think try using

```
self. DataGrab = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Save") as! String
```

and then use your DataGrab anywhere you want but use the above line to put a saved data in DataGrab

then print DataGrab 
Didload is run once try printing in Willappear when you want to check the value is stored or not
Just try